# Angular 2 routing with domain held in sub folder

Tags: angular, iis, angular2-routing

I have a sub domain, mySUBsite.com, that is physically located at myMAINsite.com/mySUBsite. I have pointer that points to this location when mySUBsite.com is called.

This is an angular 2 app and using angular routing. All routing works fine when I access via mySUBsite.com root. I am getting 404s when accessing any other routes directly eg mySUBsite.com/about. This location doesn't actually exist hence the 404.

I need some mechanism to reroute this back via the root. I've tried a redirect but I'm not 100% sure on this.

Is this possible and what would be the best way to achieve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One answer to this problem is to use hash urls. I'd rather not as they don't look as good but they do solve the problem of 404s on deep linking. Add useHash: true in your app routing module (or app module)

```
 RouterModule.forRoot(
      appRoutes,
      { useHash: true }
    )
```